PowerAutomate Custom connector trigger throwing error 405
I'm trying to create a custom connector in the MS PowerPlatform to the Exact Online API. I managed to authenticate to the environment and insert (POST) and retrieve (GET) data into and from the system.
I now want to create a trigger that will fire when a record is added or modified on an entity in the system, for this I created a trigger in the custom connector.
But when I test the trigger I get a 500 error with in the body these details:
{
  "error": {
    "code": "",
    "message": {
      "lang": "",
      "value": "Invalid: Post to callback URL endpoint returns 405 Method Not Allowed"
    }
  }
}

I followed the below description and it seems to work, but I seem to have something wrong in the configuration of the callback that doesn't seem to accept the POST request comming back from the call to the webhook registration.
https://support.exactonline.com/community/s/knowledge-base#All-All-DNO-Content-webhookstut
What am I overlooking here and what can I do to get this to work?
I setup the trigger as described in the below URL's:

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/connectors/custom-connectors/create-webhook-trigger
https://support.exactonline.com/community/s/knowledge-base#All-All-DNO-Content-webhookstut

I expected to get a 200 response and use the registered webhook response body to retrieve the data from the source system. But the PowerAutomate environment responds in an unexpected way.

Based on the tutorial on https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/training/modules/create-triggers-custom-connectors/3-create-webhook-trigger I see the callback url is filled at runtime by the platform. So I'm confused that this URL would be wrong. Do you need to set any security or define the type of requests the callback will accept somewhere? If so where do you set these parameters.

I think the problem is that the reply of Exact Online on the registration is a POST which expects a 200/201 response. But the callback URL does not accept POST requests on the https://global.consent.azure-apim.net/redirect/.... URL.
Do I need to set permissions somewhere?

Please make sure the domain name being posted to matches that of the redirect URL. Also make sure that the receiving node in Power Automate accepts the HTTP method and payload Exact provides (when down, it will retry a number of times before dropping the event).
Directly receiving the request on Power platform might be challenging at least. Please note that the webhook on registration always fires a test connection to ensure that the node is running. Please note also that de-registration of a webhook subscription when the credentials of the user or client are not available is best done through Exact Online Support.
You might find some tips on:
https://forums.invantive.com/t/exact-online-webhooks-verwerken-via-invantive-cloud/4541 (Dutch)
Please note that Exact Online Premium will be offering exactly this functionality in the future as visible in the picture at https://forums.invantive.com/t/gebruik-power-automate-met-exact-online/4534#verschil-met-power-automate-in-exact-online-premium-13.
It might be wise to wait for this functionality to become available.
In our case we process the webhook events through a dedicated node with IIS that does routing etc. You might be able to some module able to receive the webhook events on the Azure or Power platform similar to this or the URL mentioned above. This can also do load balancing; during upgrades or backup/restore that can be a million webhook event arriving within a few minutes. A separate event is triggered for each row being deleted/restored in case of a backup being handled in Exact Online. The same holds for upgrades of Exact Online itself during the night.
